# Discord.Py Opus Heroku Issues

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py, opus

I'm having trouble setting up my music bot to work with Heroku. It works perfectly fine on my host machine, however, I get an "Opus Not Loaded" error when I run the bot in Heroku. I already have a ffmpeg buildpack(https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git), an apt buildpack (https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git) with the Aptfile fully setup (see below), and I have an opus buildpack (https://github.com/dubsmash/heroku-buildpack-opus.git). I also have youtube_dl and discord.py[voice] in my requirements.txt file

Here is the contents of my Aptfile.

```
build-essential
unzip
software-properties-common
libopus-dev
libffi-dev
libsodium-dev
```

Here is the contents of my requirements.txt file

```
discord.py[voice]
youtube_dl
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support sending outbound UDP packets.

Image from the official discord.py server :

[image: warning]